Borrow checker and &mut borrows for generic params
Why can I not borrow &mut x multiple times when using is_mut_t. But it's fine with is_mut_specific ?
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use std::marker::PhantomData;

    #[test]
    fn test_wc() {
        struct Test<T>{ phantom_data: PhantomData<T>}
        impl <T> Test<T> {
            fn new() -> Self {
                Test { phantom_data: PhantomData }
            }
            fn is_mut_t(&mut self, i: T) {}
            fn is_mut_specific(&mut self, i: &mut i32) {}
        }

        let mut x = 5;
        let mut t: Test<&mut i32> = Test::new();
        
        t.is_mut_specific(&mut x);
        t.is_mut_specific(&mut x);
        // t.is_mut_t(&mut x);
        // t.is_mut_t(&mut x);
    }
}


Let's give names for lifetimes (using imaginary syntax):
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use std::marker::PhantomData;

    #[test]
    fn test_wc() {
        struct Test<T> { phantom_data: PhantomData<T> }
        impl<T> Test<T> {
            fn new() -> Self {
                Test { phantom_data: PhantomData }
            }
            fn is_mut_t<'a>(&'a mut self, i: T) {}
            fn is_mut_specific<'b, 'c>(&'b mut self, i: &'c mut i32) {}
        }

        let mut x = 5;
        let mut t: Test<&'d mut i32> = Test::new();
        
        (&'e mut t).is_mut_specific::<'e, 'f>(&'f mut x);
        (&'g mut t).is_mut_specific::<'g, 'h>(&'h mut x);
        // (&'i mut t).is_mut_t::<'i>(&'j mut x);
        // (&'k mut t).is_mut_t::<'k>(&'l mut x);
    }
}

Each occurrence of T is replaced by &'d mut i32. Can you spot the problem?
When we say &mut i32 in the signature, that gets assigned a generic lifetime that can be any.
But when we say T, that must be exactly the same as T. And that includes the same lifetime. But if we borrow x for 'd, we cannot borrow it again in 'd, which means at least as long as t exists.

Thanks for the response. So if I am understanding correctly the root cause is that the compiler has given the instance of T used in is_mut_t a hidden lifetime (that differs from self) ?
I tried the following changes: fn is_mut_t(&mut self, i: &mut T) {} and then let mut t: Test<i32> = Test::new();.  When expressed this way things compile with the is_mut_t calls uncommented.
Shouldn't it also fail in this case without lifetime annotations ?

@HassanSyed Again, replace T with some type. If that type contains a lifetime, the lifetime must be the same. If the lifetime is (elided) in the method, it is replaced by a generic lifetime.

@HassanSyed another way to look at it is that 'd, 'j and 'l must be the same lifetime (because T is equal to &'d mut i32 per the declaration of t and is also equal to &'j mut i32 and 'l mut i32 per the two is_mut_t calls). When you take the reference out of the T you break then link between the lifetimes, allowing the compiler to choose 'j != 'l.

You already have an answer to your direct question - that T as &mut i32 has an implicit lifetime that is used for all values of T which in your code would mean multiple mutable references at the same "time" - however I would like to offer a potential workaround.
It is often preferable to design your API to cater to one thing or another: references or owned values. Your's is suited to owned values since non-Copy Ts also have the same "problem" that you can't call is_mut_t twice on the same value (since was moved in the first call).
However if you want to keep this design but also keep some flexibility from references, then you can introduce a "reborrow" method to shrink the generic lifetime. Something like this:
impl<'a, T> Test<&'a mut T> {
    fn reborrow_mut(&mut self) -> Test<&'_ mut T> {
        Test { phantom_data: PhantomData }
    }
}

let mut x = 5;
let mut t: Test<&mut i32> = Test::new();

t.reborrow_mut().is_mut_t(&mut x);
t.reborrow_mut().is_mut_t(&mut x);

Full code on the Playground.
The method allows you to create a new Test<&mut T> with a shorter lifetime derived from &self which the compiler can shrink to just the method call. This mimics the compiler ability to reborrow references implicitly (as is done for your .is_mut_specific() calls), but just in a more manual way.
